# Unable to replace Inf with custom value in a dplyr chain using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
  identifier shift_back_max shift_forward_max
  <chr>               <dbl>             <dbl>
1 11                   -140                 0
2 12                    -63               149
3 13                    -37               327
4 14                      0               193
5 16                   -Inf               Inf
6 17                   -Inf               Inf
7 18                   -Inf               Inf
8 19                   -Inf               Inf
```

I am trying to replace `-inf` with `-30` and `Inf` with `30`.

I tried the below case when the approach. Please note that this case when is part of a large dplyr chain. but it's only this line which throws an error. So, am providing it here for one column

```
mutate(shift_back_max= case_when(
    (!is.na(shift_back_max)|!is.infinite(shift_back_max) ~'-30',
    TRUE ~ shift_back_max))
```

However, I get the below error message

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `shift_back_max`.
x 'from' must be a finite number
i Input `shift_back_max` is `case_when(...)`.
i The error occurred in row 5.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(shift_back_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(shift_back_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In min(shift_back_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In min(shift_back_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In min(shift_forward_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In min(shift_forward_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
7: In min(shift_forward_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
8: In min(shift_forward_max, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
 identifier shift_back_max shift_forward_max
  <chr>               <dbl>             <dbl>
1 11                   -140                 0
2 12                    -63               149
3 13                    -37               327
4 14                      0               193
5 16                    -30                30
6 17                    -30                30
7 18                    -30                30
8 19                    -30                30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test if a value if infinite with `ifelse()` and then multiply its sign by 30 when TRUE:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("shift"), ~ ifelse(is.infinite(.x), 30 * sign(.x), .x)))

  identifier shift_back_max shift_forward_max
1         11           -140                 0
2         12            -63               149
3         13            -37               327
4         14              0               193
5         16            -30                30
6         17            -30                30
7         18            -30                30
8         19            -30                30
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. If I multiply a minus sign by 30 times, it will become positive right?

Comment: How does `30 * sign(.x), .x` part correctlt places `-30` on `shift_back_max` and `+30` on `shift_forward_max`?

Comment: can you please break the above step for me to understand please?

Comment: `sign()` evaluates to `1` for a positive number and `-1` for a negative number so becomes `30 * -1` or `30 * 1` for `-Inf` or `Inf` values respectively.

Comment: Hi, one related question. can help me with this please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563903/use-of-mutate-in-summarise-function-using-r